# Filtering HTML content based on URL Variable

Tags: html, css, url, filtering

I am looking for a way that I can hide specific HTML content based on a variable in the URL.

For example, I am passing a variable: **index.html?app=new**

I have various images and other content that has a prod attribute and would like to show **only** those that have the "new" prod value.

```
<img prod="new" class="image" src="../images/screen.png" height="300" width="600"/>
```

I have used the following to harvest the url variable:

```
<script>  
  function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,
    function(m,key,value) {
    vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
  }
</script>
```

My problem is where to go from here

Answer (score 0):

I think this CSS rule will do the magic for you:

```
[prod]:not([prod=new]) { display:none; }
```

It will hide all elements having 'prod' attribute with the value other than 'new'.

Comment: I do find this interesting and have tried this also. My predicament with this (and I did not state it in the initial request) is ; how can I code that if the variable has another value?  That is, how do I handle it where there may be multiple values that could apply?  (app=new, app=whatever)

Answer (score 0):

This is untested code.

### HTML

```
<img data-prod="new" class="image" src="../images/screen.png" height="300" width="600" />
```

### JavaScript

```
<script>  
    (function(){
    'use strict';

    var getUrlVars = function() {
        var vars = {};

        window.location.href.replace(
            /[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,
            function(m,key,value) {
                vars[key] = value;
            }
        );
        return vars;
    };

    if(typeof getUrlVars.app === 'string' && getUrlVars.app === 'new') {
        var c = document.querySelectorAll('[data-prod="new"]'), i;
        for(i = 0; i < c.length; i+=1) {
            c[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
    })();
</script>
```

In the general case (i.e. app=new, app=whatever), you can substitute `new` in the querySelectorAll parameter as the variable itself:

```
if(typeof getUrlVars.app === 'string') {
    var c = document.querySelectorAll('[data-prod="' + getUrlVars.app + '"]'), i;
    for(i = 0; i < c.length; i+=1) {
        c[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```